# Request and response blocks each other

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am trying to send something like HTTP request to the server and then get the response from the server. In this time server reading my request while the client will not close outputStream. That's why server cant sends response back to the client. It is something like "deadLock". When I trying to close() outputStream on the client side, I got an exception in the line where I am reading the response, because Socket connection has been closed. How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Client:

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Programing\\WebServer\\src\\main\\java\\Client\\testimg.bmp");
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        long length = file.length();

        Files.copy(file.toPath(), out);

        out.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while ((s = reader.readLine())!=null)
            stringBuilder.append(s);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Server-side:

```
System.out.println("Handle started");

        try {

            DownloadingFile downloadingFile = new DownloadingFile();
            downloadingFile.downloadFile(in);

           writingResponse(out, "OK");
           out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In the server-side additional class:

```
public class DownloadingFile {
    public void downloadFile(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Programing\\WebServer\\src\\main\\java\\Server\\Messages\\testingimg.bmp");
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(c);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("Downloaded");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
After outputing the request, I must call

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
```